# gmail addon message.getbody permission

Tags: permissions, gmail-addons

I want to develop a gmail addon, and inside the addon, I want to call message.getbody() to get the current selected message.

But I got an error message about "URL .... does not match any of the prefixes whitelisted for use in the add-on".

Does it mean that I have to put all the email addresses into the openLinkUrlPrefixes list? How can I know what email I am going to receive in advance? How is this supposed to work please?

Right now I am using:

```
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
"https://mail.google.com/"]
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the error message. This error will occur only if you are making a UrlFetch request. It doesn't have anything to do with permission and OAuthScopes.

For example, if you are making a fetch request to stack overflow. You would need to whitelist the stack overflow URL as shown below:

```
"urlFetchWhitelist": [
   "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"
]
```

You can find documentation on this [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#whitelisting_urls).

If you are only able to resolve the URL during the runtime, then that would be a different ball game altogether.

Hope this helps.